# Are there examples in Django for making a web-page form send user submitted data to be get stored in a model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm new to Django and need to create a custom Q&A forum. I can handle the other pieces of the puzzle, but one thing I'm currently confused about is updating the model with data from the web-page that the user fills in a form and submits. Also, the user wouldn't supply all fields of the model too- for example: in a question model: they would provide the question text and the question details only and the remaining question id, created date, user id as foreign key need to get automatically saved along with the question text and details when the user hits submit.

Can someone please point me towards a working example or a definitive guide on how to do this? I referred to [Django Modelforms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example) but it confused me more than helped me as I don't think they have explained all pieces of the puzzle or its for someone more well versed with Django. Specifically, I'm a bit confused on the best way to make the form appear on a HTML template and how to collect and handle the data in the views.py i.e., should I collect the Post data on the view where the form appears or on the view where the submit button redirects it to, and before saving, how can I add to the form data so it automatically saves basic details such user_id (FK from session), datetime, question_id (PK) along with the form data.

Comment: You need to take a look official django tutorial. It covers all basic parts of django.

Answer (score 0):

The django docs are great

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/

If you have a working django environment, and you are unable to follow these very simple and clear tutorials I'm not sure what else to tell you. There are a huge variety of great django tutorials (i think djangogirls has a really great one as well) but nothing is as clean and simple as their docs.

Here is a comprehensive list:

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Tutorials